How to clear Type error in Qwik related to useContext and useStore
I'm working on converting a React application to the Qwik framework. I'd like to use context to share state with component children. The first property in the context object is a query string that is bound to an input. I'm having trouble reconciling a type error in the Child component...
import {
  $,
  component$,
  createContextId,
  useContext,
  useContextProvider,
  useStore,
} from '@builder.io/qwik';

export const MyContext = createContextId('my-context');

export type MyContextType = {
  query: string;
};

export default component$(() => {
  const myContextObj: MyContextType = useStore({
    query: '',
  });
  useContextProvider(MyContext, myContextObj);

  return (
    <Child />
  );
}

const Child = component$(() => {
  const MyContextObj = useContext(MyContext) as MyContextType;
  return (
    <>
      <input
        type="text"
        bind:value={MyContextObj.query}
      />
    </>
  );
});


The error is with bind:value, and it says Type 'string' is not assignable to type 'Signal<string | undefined>'.
In addition to the type error, the input binding doesn’t work. When I type into the input, I get Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Cannot create property 'value' on string ''.

[UPDATE]: I have just found that both problems are resolved if I replace bind:value with an onInput$ listener. Perhaps bind:value is incompatible with context...
        onInput$={(e) =>
          (myContextObj.query = (e.target as HTMLInputElement).value)
        }

